# angular 4 submit form by pressing enter with login button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

Is it possible to submit a form that have a submit button (by pressing enter)

I have two text fields by clicking the login button I am able to process the outcome but I am unable to do it by hitting enter.

Here is the HTML code(updated with full code)

this is signin.component.html

```
<div class="modal-content" style="padding: 10px;" id="login" *ngIf="show">
    <div class="modal-body text-left">
        <div class="login">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="row socialButtons">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-facebook" (click)="signInFacebook()">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook visible-xs"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Facebook</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-linked-in" (click)="signInLinkedin()">
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin visible-xs"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Linkedin</span>
                    </a>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-google-plus" (click)="signInGoogle()">
                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus visible-xs"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Google</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="signupName">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="signinPassword">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class = "error"> {{ errMsg }} </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" type="button" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()">Login</button>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">      
                    <p class="forgotPwd">
                        Forgot password? <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="reset()"> Reset</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="forgotPwd">
                        New User? <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="signup()"> Register now</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showSignUp">
  <app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showForgotPassword">
  <app-forgot-password></app-forgot-password>
</div>
```

this signin.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string;
  password:string;
  show = true;
  showSignUp = false;
  showForgotPassword = false;
  errMsg = "";

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getEmitter().subscribe(res => {
      if(res){
        this.activeModal.dismiss('success');
      }
      else{
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.errMsg = "Invalid Username/Password";
      }
    })
  }

  signInGoogle(){
    this.authService.loginWithGoogle();
  }

  signInFacebook(){
    this.authService.loginWithFacebook();
  }

  signInLinkedin(){
    this.authService.loginWithLinkedin();
  }

  logOut(){
    this.authService.logOut();
  }

  login(){
   this.authService.login(this.username,this.password);
  }

  reset(){
    this.show = false;
    this.showSignUp = false;
    this.showForgotPassword = true;
  }

  signup(){
    this.show = false;
    this.showSignUp = true;
    this.showForgotPassword = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: button type should be `type="submit"`

Comment: button type submit not working

Comment: ah, you are also missing `(ngSubmit)="mySubmitMethod()"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button should be inside the form but you have closed it inside the two input fields.

Update your code like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" (submit)="login()" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="signupName">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="signinPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
            </div>
            <div class = "error"> {{ errMsg }} </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()">Login</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use (keyup.enter)="focusableSubmit.click()" to input Password and call #focusableSubmit to Button login, this would perform the task and same for button as shown in code below.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="signupName">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="signinPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required (keyup.enter)="focusableSubmit.click()">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class = "error"> {{ errMsg }} </div>
                <button #focusableSubmit class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" type="button" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()">Login</button>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Excellent @Rahul. I had tried all the possible ways. But only your way it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Usually, you need to put your code in `action=""`. But this isn't old HTML, this is Angular, and it works with Javascript.

So, in order to do that, you need to add the `novalidate` tag, and tell the form what to do when you validate it.

You also need to declare a submit input instead of your button.

This would look like

```
<form class="loginForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="login()" autocomplete="off">

<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()"/>
```

Comment: You're joking, right ? Here is your updated code : `<form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">`

Comment: Could you please post **the code you tried after reading my answer, that didn't work ?**

Comment: here is what i have tried <form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="login()" autocomplete="off">   and yes this didn't work

Comment: So you didn't try with the input typed as submit I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161697/discussion-between-johny-bravo-and-trichetriche).

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()"/>`

Comment: Ok I give up. I asked you 3 times to post your code. You only put 2 comments, for all I know you only copy pasted my answer. So good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and quite easy!

First you have to replace

```
(button)="button()"
```

with

```
(ngSubmit)="login()"
```

and remove the click handler from the button and change the type to submit.

Both lines changed look like this:

```
<form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="login()" method="POST">
```

and:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Login</button
```

*Dont forget that this way, that button() does not get called.*

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) is really helpful on most of the generel topics, maybe you should take a look there.

Additionally you should consider reading up on some basic information about forms. I personally suggest: [forms on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and  [buttons on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strapped version of my form for sending comments.
As you see, I prevented the ENTER event on textarea and that will cause pressing ENTER while focused on textarea to not make a new line (but you can use SHIFT + ENTER).
Pressing enter sends a form.

```
<form #addCommentForm="ngForm" (keydown.enter)="addComment(addCommentForm.value)">
    <textarea (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" type="text" placeholder="Leave a comment..." name="description" #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="comment.description"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btnlog" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()">Login</button>`